# iOS access nowPlayingInfo post to web service

Tags: ios, swift, html

I want to develop a way to access the currently playing audio track on an iOS device, and send that information to a remote web service.

Can this be done with HTML 5 code so that it will run in Safari, or can only dedicated apps written in swift or objective-c access the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information isn't available from within Safari. Only installed (non-web clip) apps can access `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this.